# To create piechart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

Below is my JSON format of data from which I want to create a pie chart in highcharts..

```
{
  "title": {"text": "Pie"},

  "series": 
  [
    {
        "type": "pie",
        "name": "Actual",
        "data": 
         [
            [
                "Salesgrowth",
                45
            ],
            [
                "marketshare",
                26.8
            ]
         ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is valid JSON , I am getting this output from Web Service, when I call this service and evoke this method to run this JSON output to create pie then I get the error as follows,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'renderTo' of undefined
```

Below is the JQuery function that I make use to call my file where I stored this JSON output from my web service,

```
function loadJson() {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           //alert("inside");
           var chart;
           var seriesData;
           $.getJSON("val1.json", function (data) {
               var chartoptions = data;
               chartoptions.chart.renderTo = 'container';
               chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartoptions);

           });

       });
   },
```

and this function runs well with other kind of charts like bar graph,line graph and column graph...tested with all kinds of graphs, I am facing problem only with pie chart...any help will be greatly appreciated

---------Updated question------
 Below is my JSON output I have changed in order to get values

```
{
   "title":{"text":"Financial"},
   "chart":{"type":"pie"},
   "series":
     [ {"name":"Actual-Market Share","data":["Market Share",30]},{"name":"Actual-Market Share","data":["Sales Growth",70]}]}
```

and below is the output I am getting,

I am not able to identify what I am exactly messing with...Any idea will be of great help...

[image]

----------Updated output-----------

```
  {
    "legend":{"enabled":"true"},
    "title":{"text":"Financial"}, 
    "chart":{"type":"pie"},
    "series":[{"name":"Actual","data":[{"str":"Market Share","flo":20}]},
              {"name":"Actual","data":[{"str":"Sales Growth","flo":30}]},
              {"name":"Actual","data":[{"str":"Operating Profit","flo":40}]},
              {"name":"Actual","data":[{"str":"Gross Margin %","flo":10}]}]}
```

Comment: Don't change your series object. The one you posted originally looked fine. Try my solution with the original data object.

Comment: Hey @SteveP..I did that..but its not working..

Comment: Try again. I had a typo.

Comment: @SteveP..thanks ..it worked..I was messing with one comma..Thanks a lott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json doesn't include a chart object, so setting chart.renderTo won't work.

If you can change the webservice, get it to add the following to your json:

```
 chart: {
    },
```

If you can't change the back end, you can change your javascript to add the chart object before setting renderTo:

```
$.getJSON("val1.json", function (data) {
           var chartoptions = data;
           if (typeof chartoptions.chart === 'undefined')  {
               chartoptions.chart = {};
           }
           chartoptions.chart.renderTo = 'container';
           chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartoptions);
       });
```

Comment: Thanks..but if you see my updated question then you will come to know I have included the chart tag as well..can you look for the updated issue..it will be very grateful for me then..Thank you,

Comment: ..can you please check my updated output and tell me whats wrong with it..I am not able to draw the pie chart...

Comment: Your series data is wrong. You need one series object with multiple data points. The series in your original code was correct.

Comment: @SteveP... Can You tell me how can I take two arguments in list..Please see my below link for complete question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490623/how-to-add-multiple-data-types-to-list].. and problem is when I serialize my final variable it gives me content of data as string:float which is not the required format