# How to add multiple data types to list

Tags: c#, json, list, highcharts

I have my list as below,

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name , data =new List<float?>() };
```

In the above code data in another list which contains float value, I want data to contains two different datatype value that is string and float value, when I am trying to add two different datatype values as follow,

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name , data =new List<string, float?>() };
```

It gives me an error as
 `Using the generic type'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 argument.`

I cannot try for `data=new List<Tupple<string,float>>();`..since I am using .NET 3.5...any idea..hw cn I deal with this problem..thank you,

----------Updated question---------

Output that I requires is as follows,

```
 {
 "legend":{"enabled":"true"},
 "title":{"text":"Financial"},
 "chart":{"type":"pie"},
 "series":
  [
    {"name":"Actual-","data":[["Market Share",20.00],["Sales Growth",30.00],["Operating Profit",40.00],["Actual-Gross Margin %",10.00]]}
  ]
  },
```

this data list should contains one string value and one float value...I want to draw pie chart in highcharts but output I am getting is as follows,

```
{
"legend":{"enabled":"true"},
"title":{"text":"Financial"},
"chart":{"type":"column"},
"series":[{"name":"Actual","data":[{"Str":"Market Share","Flo":20.00}]},
          {"name":"Actual","data":[{"Str":"Sales Growth","Flo":30.00}]},
          {"name":"Actual","data":[{"Str":"Operating Profit","Flo":40.00}]},
          {"name":"Actual","data":[{"Str":"Gross Margin %","Flo":10.00}]}
         ]
}
```

Any Idea...???

----------Use of Dictionary----------

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, float?>();
var serie_line = new { name = series_name, data };
serie_line.data.Add(child_object_name, period_final_value);
```

but this doesnot give required output...
it only gives values inside data as for eg,
     "data":["market share":20.00].. since I am serializing serie_line into JSON...but I don't want this way..what I want is "data":["market share",20.00]

I hope u get this...

Comment: DO you want a list of objects or do you want a list of Tuples (or their equivalent)? ie are your strings and floats a one to one mapping or is it just that you might have something like `{1,2,3,"four"}` in your list?

Comment: @chries...I want my data list to give output as {"string",1}

Comment: So are you only going to have two items in the list ever? If so why a list?

Comment: Then what you suggest to me instead of list?

Comment: Ah, I see you've updated the question as well to give what you actually want to do. You should always consider asking the question about what you want to do rather than what you think you need.

Comment: .k...sorry for half question but can U suggest me any solution..what should I do achieve this output...thank you,

Comment: I have tried with list,dictionary and creating class and then using its object but i am not able to get the required output so far

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JSON serialisers but I would hope that if you had a simple object with properties of `name` and `data` then it would serialise it as `{"name": "Actual", "data": [...]}`. If so then  you just need to create the appropriate classes and serialise. I've not got a way to test this though.

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
 new Dictionary<string, float?>() //if your string value cannot be duplicated
```

//or

```
  new  List<KeyValuePair<string,float?> >
```

Comment: From the original question: "I cannot try for `data=new List<Tupple<string,float>>();`"

Comment: I have updated my  answer  keyvaluepair is supported in  .net 3.5

Comment: when I am using the dictionary..I am getting output as below "series":[{"name":"Actual","data":[{"Str":"Market Share","Flo":22.37}]}]...this format I have got because I serailaize the my variable in JSON format since my main aim is to draw pie chart in highcharts bt I don't want this output...please c my updated question...

Comment: how you are using  dictionary  I can't see your updated question

Answer (score 3):

create a type to be use with your list:

```
public class MyDataType
{
  public string Str {get; set;}
  public float? Flo {get;set;}
}
```

you use it like this:

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name , data =new List<MyDataType>() };
serie_line.data.Add(new MyDataType{Flo = 45.4});
```

or like:

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name , data =new List<MyDataType>() };
serie_line.data.Add(new MyDataType{Flo = 45.4, Str = "my string"});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add items to a list so that both are available you need to use `List<object>()`, as its the only shared type between both. That or use ArrayList.

As you pull the objects out you will need to test if they are objects of type `string` or `float?` in order to cast them back. You may be able to wrap them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.90%29), the non-generic version of List.

Answer (score 0):

How about something more structured:

```
public struct MyData
{
    public float? FloatData;
    public string StringData;
}

var serie_line = new
                 {
                     name = series_name,
                     data = new MyData()
                            {
                                FloatData = theFloatData,
                                StringData = theStringData,
                            }
                 };
```